# ¿Cómo seguir con la descarga de un archivo si se cae la conexión?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, socket, descarga

Estoy descargando algunos archivos usando urllib.request y urllib3 en un método recursivo pero cuando la red falla el programa se para y da error. Mi intención es que si la red falla el script siga intentando la conexión hasta que se establezca y siga descargando por el archivo que se quedó. Creo que no hilos o con socket se puede hacer algo pero no sé como ¿Alguna idea?

Tengo este método recursivo para buscar los archivos que me interesan y descargarlos:

```
def dfs(url):
    if ".deb" in url:
        print(url)  
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "D:\ejemplo\ file.deb")

    else:
        req = http.urlopen("GET", url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.data, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            if link.get('href') != "../":
                dfs(url + link.get('href'))
```

Los errores que se producen son:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder

urllib.error.URLError:<urlopen error [WinError 10060] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder>
```